# Segmentation fault debugger for Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

Can we use gdb to debug segmentation faults for Qt programs. If no are there any other tools which can do the task for Qt programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can debug a Qt program with gdb, or any other debugger that supports C++ for that matter. Qt is just a C++ library, Qt source code is just C++ source code making use of  Qt libraries.